# Grails self referencing domain class surprising save result

Tags: grails, insert, self-reference

I have a self-referencing domain class like this:

```
class Person {
   String name
   Person father
   Person mother
}
```

I have no hasMany or other constraints on father or mother

I have a service that inserts new entries from a .csv file as follows

```
Person father = Person.findBy(newPersonFatherName)
Person mother = Person.findBy(newPersonMotherName)
Person newPerson = new Person(
    name: newPersonName,
    father: father,
    mother: mother)
newPerson.save()
```

What happens when this is executed is the maternal grandmother and paternal grandfather are both set to the same instance as newPerson.

I can make this go away by inserting the following two lines before the save()

```
Person pgf = father.father
Person pgm = father.mother
Person mgf = mother.father
Person mgm = mother.mother
```

I guess the whole thing is somehow related to cascading saves but I'm unable to really understand the problem, and I'm reluctant to leave such a poorly understood solution in place in the code.

Can anyone help?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure what `findBy` does on it's own, shouldn't it be `findByName`? Also a name isn't very unique, after a while `findByName` isn't going to get you the correct result as it finds the first matching result

Comment: Hi Mike,  and thanks for the comments.  Briefly, the above is a simplified version of what I really have where I have got rid of unrelated attributes etc.  Then, in this case 'findBy' should be 'findByName' in this example as you state (I used findBy with other attributes in the real thing; you can find examples of it in the Grails documentation).  And as to the uniqueness your point is correct and in the real thing I use other attributes as well, in the 'findBy'.  But in the end, the behaviour is what I mention, ie the grandparents somehow are incorrectly updated by the original code.

Comment: Best bet is to create an example project and link it here

Comment: At James Kleeh's advice I created a sample project, which shows the same weird behaviour under Grails 2.5.5 latest.  I decided I'd try it under Grails 3.3.0 as I'm moving my stuff there shortly, and the problem seems to have gone away.  So I'm marking this solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this problem has gone away somewhere between Grails 2.5.5 and Grails 3.3 so I'm going to mark this as answered and solved.